# Koin geProperty() in KoinComponent not resolved

Tags: koin

## Koin 2.0.0-beta-1

I can only getProperty("SERVICE") in Appmodule. In Activity, Fragment, ViewModel, and Service, can't use getProperty.

Has something changed in beta?

Answer (score 1):

If we examine the src code for [KoinComponent](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/master/koin-projects/koin-core/src/main/kotlin/org/koin/core/KoinComponent.kt) we see the 'getKoin()' function that returns the Koin instance. 
In the src code for the [Koin class](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/master/koin-projects/koin-core/src/main/kotlin/org/koin/core/Koin.kt)  we find the required 'getProperty'

see below for a simple use case

```
import org.koin.Logger.slf4jLogger
import org.koin.core.KoinComponent
import org.koin.core.context.startKoin
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

class Runner : KoinComponent {
    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("entry")

    companion object {
      @JvmStatic
      fun main(args: Array<String>) {
          startKoin {
            slf4jLogger()
            fileProperties()
            modules()
        }
      val runner = Runner()
      runner.initVals()
       }
    }

    fun initVals() {
      logger.info("koin is go")
      val url: String? = getKoin().getProperty("SERVER_URL")
      logger.info("koin properties is go ${url}")
    }
}

// koin.properties in src/main/resources
SERVER_URL=https://some_server_url
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't know that. Thanks again.